# Is it possible to shoot an Aurora Borealis with a Panasonic Lumix DMC-FX35

Tags: panasonic-lumix, aurora-borealis

I'm planning to go to Alaska to see Aurora Borealis and I have a Panasonic Lumix DMC-FX35.

Is it possible to get **decent** pictures of Auroras using this camera?

Here are the specs of this camera: http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/FX35/FX35DAT.HTM

If it is not possible, which is the cheapest camera+lens setup I can buy to get a picture of an Aurora?

Thanks,
Randall

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an excellent article entitled ["How to Photograph the northern lights"](http://www.alaskaphotographics.com/how_to_photograph_northern_lights.shtml#gear) that basically states with a point and shoot, it's very difficult to get good pictures. It looks like your camera is one of the higher-end, it should be alright, they have some specific recommendations that I've copied below. It also gives a list of cameras that might do the trick. Good luck!

If you have an digi cam with some advanced features, read your manual and see if it looks usable for aurora. You want:

1. 400 ISO, preferably 800 or higher
2. bulb mode
3. manual focus option
4. self timer release
5. wide angle lens

Comment: +1 - Good article and, as an added bonus, yet another reason that the UV filter is more of a pain than it's worth!

Comment: I have the DMC-FX35, great little camera but don't think it will be up to the job. Maybe you could rent kit?